# Is this INSERT statement containing SELECT subquery safe for multiple concurrent writes?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

In Postgres, suppose I have the following table to be used like to a singly linked list, where each row has a reference to the previous row.

```
                       Table node
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |       Default
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------
 id          | uuid                     |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 created_at  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 name        | text                     |           | not null |
 prev_id     | uuid                     |           |          |
```

I have the following INSERT statement, which includes A SELECT to look up the last row as data for the new row to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO node(name, prev_id)
VALUES (
  :name,
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM node
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
)
RETURNING id;
```

I understand storing `prev_id` may seem redundant in this example (ordering can be derived from `created_at`), but that is beside the point.  My question: Is the above INSERT statement safe for multiple concurrent writes?  Or, is it necessary to explicitly use `LOCK` in some way?

For clarity, by "safe", I mean is it possible that by the time the SELECT subquery executed and found the "last row", another concurrent query would have just finished an insert, so the "last row" found earlier is no longer the last row, so this insert would use the wrong "last row" value.  The effect is multiple rows may share the same `prev_id` values, which is invalid for a linked list structure.

Comment: Not sure about safety (eventhough I guess it is not safe). But if your ```node``` table really shall only be a list and not a tree (or forest) you might think of adding a ```UNIQUE``` index on ```prev_id```.

Comment: If with "safe" you mean, that no two INSERT will wind up with the same `prev_id`, then no. This is not safe.

Comment: @Islingre I need `prev_id` to be nullable, and this table would actually represent multiple singly linked lists, so `UNIQUE` index is not applicable.

Comment: @Andy Shih The ```null``` values are not checked in a ```UNIQUE```, so this is no problem.

Comment: @Islingre Thank you. This `UNIQUE` constraint is exactly what I need here, to enforce the data structure, instead of worrying about concurrency.

Comment: Worrying about concurrency would also be good because now you might get errors on insertion.